# Qt.Как создать модульное приложение?

Tags: c++, qt

Как создать модульную структуру проекта, как на рисунке :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтоб в папке src находились модули состоящие из .pri файлов, шапки .h файлов, ui и .cpp файлов. Сейчас всё в куче :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что тут выбирать? :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, вроде как, надо не тип проекта менять а просто "модули" добавить.

Comment: @outoftime  А по подробней можно ? Так не чего не понятно и я не тип проекта меняю , а добавляю в проект файлы

Comment: Модульное приложение: https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager. В `pro` файле через `include` подключаются модули: `include( Manager/Manager.pri )`

Comment: @gil9red А как создать такие модули самому с .pri файлами ? В этом и вопрос

Comment: Ну так вы откройте pri файл из репозитория да полюбопытствуйте, как он устроен. Многое прояснится.

Comment: @Bearded Beaver В .pri файле есть : INCLUDEPATH, DEPENDPATH, HEADERS и SOURCES . Но я так и не могу найти как добавить его в Qt Creator . Этот файл типа .pro

Comment: Создайте его как обычный текстовый файл и добавьте в свой проект строчкой в pro файле, как вам показали выше

Comment: @Bearded Beaver А ну теперь ясно. Только я думал его можно добавить в меню  Qt Creator . Странно что через меню Qt Creator это не делается

Answer (score 2):

Для версии QtCreator 4.5:

Создать>Другой проект>Проект с поддиректориями

Будет создан проект, куда можно добавлять подпроекты. Можно будет указывать зависимость между ними, из которой автоматически рассчитывается порядок компиляции.

Однако я рекомендую вручную писать pro-файлы.

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs #Тип проекта

CONFIG += ordered #Собираем по порядку, как указано

SUBDIRS += \
    osm_elements \
    tests \
    osm_widget

tests.depends = osm_widget #Так обозначается зависимость
osm_widget.depends = osm_elements
```

[image: Код соответствует вот такой структуре]

TEMPLATE обозначает тип проекта. В данном случае - проект с поддиректориями.

```
TEMPLATE=app #Приложение
TEMPLATE=lib #Библиотека
TEMPLATE=subdirs #Проект с подпроектами
```

Почитайте в QtCreator справку, qmake, раздел Getting Started.